# How to set up jest for testing canvas

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, canvas, jestjs

Can't run jest tests with canvas. I have functions that's work with canvas, context, dom etc. How to set up jest correctly for that?

I have tried to use jest-canvas-mock, but how to install it correctly?

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ***
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
    ***
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ***
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ]
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
  ],
};
```

console.log:

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'imageSmoothingEnabled' of null

      15 |       const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      16 |       const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    > 17 |       context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
         |       ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to install `jest-canvas-mock` library into package.json.

```
npm install --dev jest-canvas-mock
```

Then import it into your test file.

```
import 'jest-canvas-mock'
```

Comment: This is fine to get started, but I'd love to see an example test to get a better idea of how to use this mock.

Comment: @AndyPreston Have you checked their documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock ?

Comment: Yes, there was plenty of detail there, but for a newbie, there was no simple "getting started" info... in the end, I went to their tests at https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock/blob/master/__tests__/classes/CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale.js and worked out what I needed to do based on that.